# What does "Roger" mean in war movies?

Tags: expressions

Is "roger" equivalent to "Ok"? I hear it in war movies, movies like *Star Wars Clone Wars*, and in war games.

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44220/whats-the-meaning-of-the-word-roger-over-and-out

Comment: This can be definitively answered by looking at the [wikipedia article for roger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger#Radio_phraseology)

Answer (score 42):

It's not necessarily military, it's more *radio slang*.

In certain [radio alphabets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_alphabet) *Roger* stands for the letter *R*, which in radio communications stands for *received*.

Comment: I didn't know this - I actually thought it meant "Ok" (and I am a native english speaker).  Thanks!

Comment: @BlueRaja: The meaning is similar, and because of the common use of this in war movies etc. it has also been quite popular to use it in daily speach as a synonym to "OK".

Comment: + 1 **roger that** = **received that**

Comment: It's not really radio 'slang', it's radio terminology.

Comment: @DJ: OED defines slang as `The special vocabulary or phraseology of a particular calling or profession` so I think it's not particularly wrong to use.

Comment: @nico: that's actually the definition of *jargon*, not *slang*. But who are we to argue with the mighty OED? :D

Comment: @Martha: I'm not a native English speaker, so it's very likely you guys are right and I am wrong... but I've always considered slang and jargon as synonyms....

Comment: @nico: Certainly 'slang' is slang for 'jargon', but I don't think 'slang' is jargon for 'jargon'.

Answer (score 32):

"Roger" is from WWII-era radio code for the letter "R", and was used as a more-understandable shorthand for "Received", an acknowledgement of the message. More recently, radio shorthand has moved to "copy" (an exact synonym) or "wilco" (short for "will comply" and appropriate for commands).

Comment: Also: "roger wilco" for "understood and will comply."

Comment: Also "roger roger" if you're a cool *Star Wars* patois-speaking robot.

Comment: @Joe Blow — I love the parallel evolution of "roger roger" in the prequels and "kk" online. :-D

Comment: Don't forget "Roger, Roger. What's our vector, Victor?" from the movie Airplane.

Comment: @The Raven 'Note that "ROGER" and "WILCO" are mutually exclusive, since WILCO includes the acknowledgement of ROGER.' from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedure_word#WILCO

Comment: @Joel I once named a [Vector](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) "victor".

Comment: @matt, "mutually exclusive" generally means "one but not the other." Since "wilco" includes "roger," you might say that "'roger' is implicit in 'wilco.'" @Joel Spolsky Let's not forget "Do we have clearance, Clarance?"

Comment: @rajah: In the U.S. military, they're mutually exclusive, because you're taught never to use them together.  If you say "Roger, wilco" to a late-era soldier, they're going to think you're: a) an idiot, or b) a poseur.

Answer (score 12):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger#Radio_phraseology)

> "Roger" means "I have received all of
>   the last transmission" in both
>   military and civilian aviation radio
>   communications. This usage comes from
>   the initial R of received: R was
>   called Roger in the radio alphabets
>   current at the time, such as the Joint
>   Army/Navy Phonetic Alphabet. It is
>   also often shortened in writing to
>   "rgr". R is Romeo in the modern NATO
>   phonetic alphabet.

Comment: Technically "message received and understood".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, *roger* or *roger that* means *message received*. From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roger):

> used especially in radio and signaling
>   to indicate that a message has been
>   received and understood